# Zoo Visitor How to set it up

Tags: zoo-visitor

I have set up many sites in EE however I seem to have brain farted on how to use Zoo Visitor and how and where to begin? I have looked at the documentation and seem to be missing a step. Need a push in the right direction.

The concept is I have 2 groups (employees and employers) 
and need to set up each so that when they login they get access to that particular groups content.

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried? How far have you got? Depending on exactly what you need, you might not even need Zoo Visitor. You can use conditionals and global variables to display different content in a template like:

```
{if member_group == '7'}  You're an "Employee"!  {/if}
```

See [here](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/conditionals.html#member-group) in the docs for some more info. If you can be more specific I might be able to offer more assistance.